# How to set title and its content in section listview using json

Tags: android, json, listview

Hi I have following json response

http://pastebin.com/Uce9YH2h

I want to set title for heading in listview and static text as content in sublistview. but the issue is that i am able to set title only but its content is not setting properly.can any one help me with that?

I am following this example

https://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-sectioned-headers-in-listviews/

```
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response
                .get(i);
        System.out.println("Product Response" + person);
        JSONArray itemlist = person.optJSONArray("staticInfoDetails");
        JSONArray policyDetails = person.optJSONArray("policyDetails");
        JSONArray otherDetailsAndroid = person.optJSONArray("otherDetailsAndroid");



            for (int j = 0; j < itemlist.length(); j++) {

                JSONObject itmobj = (JSONObject) itemlist
                        .get(j);


                JSONArray sections=itmobj.optJSONArray("staticDetails");
                subcat_list=new ArrayList<String>();
                for(int a=0;a<sections.length();a++)
                {
                    JSONObject secitmobj = (JSONObject) sections
                            .get(a);

                   // subcat_list.add(secitmobj.getString("sortID"));
                    subcat_list.add(secitmobj.getString("staticText"));
                   // subcat_list.add(secitmobj.getString("staticPath"));
                }

                moreheaderlist.add(itmobj.getString("title"));

        }
        for (int j = 0; j < policyDetails.length(); j++) {

            JSONObject itmobj = (JSONObject) policyDetails
                    .get(j);


            moreheaderlist.add(itmobj.getString("title"));
            JSONArray sections=itmobj.optJSONArray("staticDetails");
            for(int a=0;a<sections.length();a++)
            {
                JSONObject secitmobj = (JSONObject) sections
                        .get(a);

                // subcat_list.add(secitmobj.getString("sortID"));
                subcat_list.add(secitmobj.getString("staticText"));
                // subcat_list.add(secitmobj.getString("staticPath"));
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < otherDetailsAndroid.length(); j++) {

            JSONObject itmobj = (JSONObject) otherDetailsAndroid
                    .get(j);
            moreheaderlist.add(itmobj.getString("title"));
        }


    }

    adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(MoreActivity.this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> listadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MoreActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, subcat_list);

    // Add Sections
    for (int a = 0; a < moreheaderlist.size(); a++)
    {
        adapter.addSection(moreheaderlist.get(a), listadapter);
    }
    journalListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    System.out.println("Product Response" + subcat_list);




} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   /* Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
    System.out.println("ProductList Response Error"+e.getMessage());
}
```

For Example i want ouput like this

https://andytsui.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/step6.png

Comment: You can use header listview. See this example. http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android

Comment: but how to set data ?

Comment: use RcyclerView. it have deafult viewType. Check and inflate different layout with different value

Comment: any example you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try ExpendableListView for such examples

Comment: seriously!! is this answer or comment

Comment: i can show you the sample code but it would go for 3-4 pages so i just mention that example

Comment: if you think its better go through this link

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: well it is not my issue..but i got some idea from that..thanks

Comment: i need one help

Comment: how can i get staticpath positions?

Comment: i didn't get you. for what and whose static path you need

Comment: i have one key below the statictext in response..in which i am getting url..i need to access that..it is for staticImg

Comment: do you want to access url associated in child holder class

Comment: yes exatly..if user click on about us,then i need to acces its staticimg field

Comment: i tried such example by the use of pojo classes or simply list inside another list with some keys... where i use key names as headers and the child list as child object for that list

Comment: i know using pojo its easy,without pojo any idea?

Comment: no not yet ... but your concept seems interesting... i would definitely try my best to sort this out.... just explain me what you trying to do ... just overview rest i will try.

Comment: as said that listview with header and if user click on any child get its img path